# Getting print cancelled notification in IE using IOlecommandTarget::QueryStatus

Tags: internet-explorer, plugins, com

Is it possible to be notified if a user selects cancel button from the printing prompt in IE ? Basically I want a print-cancelled kind of notification.

I read somewhere that IOlecommandtarget interface can be used to be notified for our own controls, but can the same be used for system controls like print ? Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `IOleCommandTarget::Exec` Method you will get `OLECMDERR_E_CANCELED` as return value on cancel.

Comment: But I haven't added any controls of my own. I want to query the status of already present browser printing controls.